# Cast from double[] to long in C#

Tags: c#

i declare:

```
double[] DataBuff1 = Enumerable.Repeat((double)0, 50000).ToArray();
double[] DataBuff2 = Enumerable.Repeat((double)0, 50000).ToArray();
```

then use a function with the following inputs:

```
rc = UploadData(ref (long)(DataBuff1), ref (long)(DataBuff2), ref NodeCnt, ref  NodeDataPointsPerPacket, ref TotalDataSize);
```

the function is:

```
private static int UploadData(ref long[] p1, ref long[] p2, ref int NodeCnt, ref int NodeDataPointsPerPacket, ref int TotalDataSize)
```

i have an error on `ref (long)(DataBuff1)` :

> cannot convert type `double[]` to `long`

can you please help me?

Comment: well...do you understand why you have that error?

Comment: the issue is between a value and an array of values.

Comment: ``Enumerable.Repeat((double)0, 50000).ToArray();`` - why not simply: ``new double[50000]``?

Comment: Rinat, you're title says long[], your errormessage `long`. Which is correct?
And could you please show us the part where the error occurs?

Comment: You're not casting from `double[] to long[]`. You're casting from `double[] to long`.  But, you knew that since that's what your error says.

Comment: yes sorry, the error is when i define in upload data: ref (long)(DataBuff1)   the error is: cant convert type double[] to long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are trying to convert the whole `DataBuff1` and `DataBuff2` double array to a long array.

```
public static long[] ToLongArr(double[] arr)
{
     return arr.Select(d => (long)d).ToArray();
}
```

and use like this:

```
rc = UploadData(ref ToLongArr(DataBuff1), ref ToLongArr(DataBuff2), ref NodeCnt, ref  NodeDataPointsPerPacket, ref TotalDataSize);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be a ``reinterpret_cast<long>(d)`` here instead of a value conversion? But well, in this case it doesn't matter, because every element is ``0`` and gets converted to ``0``.

Comment: That would be in c++, but in c# using unsafe code is generally not desired unless there is a good reason.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your code to:

```
long[] dataBuff1 = new long[50000];
long[] dataBuff2 = new long[50000];
rc = UploadData(ref dataBuff1, ref dataBuff2, ref NodeCnt, ref  NodeDataPointsPerPacket, ref TotalDataSize);
```

`double` is a floating point number data type, whereas `long` is an integral number data type; both come with 64 bits in size. Having a `long[]` as buffer is easier to handle than `double[]`. Each element of arrays created with `new` is implicitly initialized with the default value - `0` for number types, `null` for object types (see [`default(T)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/xwth0h0d.aspx))